# wordpress single post content not showing

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress single blog post's content is not showing. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646872/wordpress-single-post-content-not-showing-up) and [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) but I didn't understand why it's not working. It looks good for me, is there any other files to check for this problem ?

Here is my **single.php**

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

        the_post_navigation();

        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
            comments_template();
        endif;

    endwhile; // End of the loop.
    ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() ); replace this to  get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to show the post content, you need to use `<?php the_content(); ?>` or similar.

Comment: can you explain this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php twentythirteen_post_nav(); ?>
                <?php comments_template(); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I am not using twenty thirteen, then should I need to create  twentythirteen_post_nav() ?

Answer (score 0):

On single post apge you are already on a post. You do not need this loop. You can access the data of the post for example like this:

```
<?php get_header() ?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?></div>
</div>

<?php get_footer() ?>
```

Btw. you also missed "`<?php`" in the beginning of the first line.

Comment: This is not very recommended. You atleast need a call to `the_post()` to set up proper postdata. Yes, you can leave out `have_posts()`, but then you loose the `loop_end` action hook which is sometimes quite useful to add extra stuff after the loop. BTW, `the_post()` fires the `loop_start` action

Comment: So I guess the only problem causing the white page left, maybe is the missing <?php in the first line?

Comment: No, I did not miss the <?php I miss it when posting here and I tried without loop, it's not working.

Comment: Canyou turn on debug on your wordpress installation? Are there any error logs?